# How to replace the listeners with anonymous classes in Java?

Tags: java, interface, listener, anonymous, anonymous-class

I have an interface called ClientRegistrationListener

```java
public interface ClientRegistrationListener {
     void onClientAdded(Client client);
}
```

And I also have in the main class an `ArrayList` of `ClientRegistrationListener`. In this list I add listeners for my class.

```java
listeners.add(new PrintClientListener());
```

where `PrintClientListener` is a class created in this main class

```java
class PrintClientListener implements ClientRegistrationListener, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2777987742204604236L;

    @Override
    public void onClientAdded(Client client) {
        System.out.println("Client added: " + client.getName());
    }
}
```

My question is how can I replace the listeners from the `Bank` class with
anonymous classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can anonymously implement the interface by opening a block after the `new` call:

```
listeners.add(new ClientRegistrationListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClientAdded(Client client) {
       System.out.println("Client added: " + client.getName());
   }
});
```

Or, even more elegantly, since `ClientRegistrationListener` is a functional interface (even though it's not annotated as one), you can anonymously implement it with a lambda expression:

```
listeners.add(client -> System.out.println("Client added: " + client.getName()));
```